# Firebase3 Facebook Login on android

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I'm a newbie on ionic and cordova, so I'm trying to create a facebook login using firebase. When I use ionic lab works great because on web browser is used an popup implementation, but when I`m trying to run on device, is executed based on cordova and I get the follow error:

```
"auth/internal-error"
message
:
"{"error":{"message":"(#100) The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"GQR3IezRjaw"}}"
```

My code is:

```
 loginWithFacebook() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        Facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(facebookData => {
          let provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookData.authResponse.accessToken);

          firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(provider).then(firebaseData => {
                      console.log("deu bom");
            this.af.database.list('users').update(firebaseData.uid, {
              name: firebaseData.displayName,
              email: firebaseData.email,
              provider: 'facebook',
              image: firebaseData.photoURL
            });

            observer.next();
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
                      console.log("error");
            console.log(error);
            // ...
          });
        }, error => {
          observer.error(error);
        });
      } else {

        this.af.auth.login({
          provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
          method: AuthMethods.Popup
        }).then((facebookData) => {
          this.af.database.list('users').update(facebookData.auth.uid, {
            name: facebookData.auth.displayName,
            email: facebookData.auth.email,
            provider: 'facebook',
            image: facebookData.auth.photoURL
          });
          observer.next();
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.info("erro login", error);
          observer.error(error);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

When I debug I can see the access_token, and I used this token on browser to verify if is valid, works great, but on `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential` I get the error described above.

Comment: When installing the cordova-plugin-facebook4 have you set the APP_ID variable?

Comment: Yes, I set my ID and app name.

Comment: @Ricardo Did you ever figure this out. I'm running into same deal.